# send mail with PhoneGap without opening my mailbox

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Is it possible to send an email from my PhoneGap application without being redirected to my mailbox?

I've tried this way, but here I am redirected to my mailbox?

```
<a href="mailto:Somemail@gmail.com?subject=hello world" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Email Me!</a>
```

or with EmailComposer :

```
function sendMail(){
 var password = $('#capturePassword').val();


 if (password == '' || password == null || password == undefined  ){

     alert("MasterCode missing !");


 }else{

     window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(null,"Your Password","MasterCode is "+password,null,null,false,null);

 }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in plain Javascript using AWS Library & SES Service :

1. Go to [AWS Builder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/) and select the AWS services to create your own minified .js file (I selected default services)
2. Download and include that file in your Cordova platform -> ios/android -> www folder
3. To use AWS.SES service, instantiate it as below:

   AWS.config.update({region:*region*});

   AWS.config.update({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'});

var ses = new window.AWS.SES({"accessKeyId": *your_access_key*, "secretAccessKey": *your_secret_key*, "region": *aws_region*});

NOTE : I tried invoking SES Service using Cordova AWS plugins but they did not support all services fully. This was my best run.

4. Next, use either ses.sendMail (Plain Text Email) or ses.sendRawEmail (to include attachments). This will send the email without opening up an email client.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that, you need to build a form just like any other website. From there you can send the contents in the form as an email. Might need a server for that though.

I checked the [EmailComposer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) plugin, it applies also for that. Make a form and submit the data entered in the form with the use of the plugin. Just follow the guidelines closely.